# Error "expression cannot be used as a function" in boost thread?

Tags: c++, boost

I use QT-Creator on OpenSUSE and Boost 1.55. All binaries needed are built.

The program is simple to test Boost thread is functional. Only declare a thread.

When build the program I have the following error

```
/home/esys/Documents/Boost/headers/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:117: error: expression cannot be used as a function
                 f();
                 ^
```

in thread.hpp it looks like this:

```
void run()
        {
            f();// line 117
        }

    private:
        F f;
    };
```

I'm quite confused about this because the problem seems to be the code of the header itself not a build-setting things!

How to fix this? Of course I can change to another Boost version but I'm kind of curious about this error. It's the big Boost libraries, dudes !

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: And how does _your_ code look like ?

Comment: It looks like this:
`boost::thread *p = new boost::thread("thread1");`

Comment: What's the type of `F`? Based on the compiler error it is neither a function pointer nor a type with a function call operator. Is it posisble that `F` happens to be a member function pointer? These, obviously, can't be called as if they were a normal function.

Comment: Please visit this link for the source code of the boost.hpp:  
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can [reproduce your issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f25c89e18147ee3b), the declaration of your thread :

```
boost::thread *p = new boost::thread("thread1");
```

Is not valid : the constructor expects a callable (e.g. a functor), not a `string`.
You should look at the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html) for more information.

(The error message is actually quite explicit : it tells you that your expression _ the string "thread1" _ is not callable)

**Note:**

Consider [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) as an alternative for `boost::thread`, if your compiler supports C++11.

Comment: Silly me :( Thank you! I will start looking at Boost Docs first then tutorials on the internet :(